# Ajax and checking actions in Ispostback

Tags: asp.net, ajax.net

Is there any relationship between Ajax and checking actions in Ispostback,,though both are
doing server checking without loading page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure you actually understand what AJAX is so maybe you should look at this [W3school tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp)

The main idea of the AJAX framework is to eliminate full-page postbacks. Only the relevant parts of the page are updated, without a disturbing refresh. The markup that is transferred between the client machine and the server is reduced dramatically, which results in a significant performance improvement for the user.

Comment: if we check that relevant part in Ispostback,,then wat is the differnece

Comment: the difference is Page.IsPostBack(a boolean property) checks during a Page life cycle if an event on the client side triggered the postback to the event..AJAX is used to simplify the approach of triggering a postback by only checking the important information that is used inside ajax script